# POSIXct in R strange behavior

Tags: r, posixct

I would like to ask the R gurus to comment of the following:

> as.POSIXct("05/11/1998 09:35", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="EST") - as.POSIXct("1998-05-11 09:35:00 EST")
>   Time difference of 1 hours

Shouldn't it be zero since dates are the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Not on my system: `as.POSIXct("05/11/1998 09:35", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="EST") - as.POSIXct("1998-05-11 09:35:00 EST")` 
 `Time difference of 0 secs`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg try `Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")` first.  The issue is that `tz` isn't supplied in the second call, and the OP expects "EST" to automatically be recognized as the value for the timezone (and probably also expects it to be the same as America/New_York)

Comment: You are correct.  My timezone is CST6CDT and is thus currently UTC-5.

Comment: Thanks. I think that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?strptime` (which `?as.POSIXct` points to) the `format=` argument should be

> A character string.  The default for the ‘format’ methods is
>             ‘"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"’ if any element has a time component
>             which is not midnight, and ‘"%Y-%m-%d"’ otherwise.  If
>             ‘options("digits.secs")’ is set, up to the specified number
>             of digits will be printed for seconds.

The time `"1998-05-11 09:35:00 EST"` has a format of `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"`.  However `%Z` can only be used for output (see `?strptime`)

If you provide the `tz=` argument to the second call, it will work as expected

```
> as.POSIXct("05/11/1998 09:35", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="EST") - as.POSIXct("1998-05-11 09:35:00 EST", tz="EST")
Time difference of 0 secs
```

It is worth noting that

> ```
> 'EST' is a time zone used in Canada _without_ daylight saving time, and not
>  ‘EST5EDT’ nor (Australian) Eastern Standard Time.)
> ```

(see `?timezone`)